# Windows 7 frequently crashes when running 64 bit debian on virtualbox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I've been having some hard times with Virtualbox. I use it to run 64-bit Debian guest on a  Windows 7 host to be able to code for Linux systems.

It generally crashes when I build my code in eclipse cdt, or if I am doing some intensive operations.

Should I lower the memory and core usage?  Is this some sort of virtualbox problem?

I upgraded to virtualbox v4.1.8  and the problem still occurs.

My virtual machine instance uses 1736MB out of 4GB of ram, and I use 2 out of 8 processor cores but still, the whole thing crashes 1 or 2 times every single day.

Comment: I have had no issues with VirtualBox running a 64-bit Linux Mint distro, except the occasional bootup failure, can you show your VBox settings for this VM? Like CPU settings, what mode it is in, what disks you have, any shared folders, etc... One thing I noticed is that the shared folder filesystem is quite unstable, so if you're trying to build directly in there that might be your issue.

Comment: I have one shared folder, about cpu I use 2 processors, %100 execution cap, you might be right shared folder might be the culprit, but unfortunately I need shared folders right now, I will have more info when it crashes again, I will definitely post the log file.

Comment: What you can do (and what I did) is copy the whole project folder over to the guest drive, and work there (and transfer over the shared folder only when needed). The log file would be very helpful - it could just be a mistakenly checked checkbox in the settings page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was the following, my windows 7 machine had 32 bit OS, when I format it and installed a 64 bit OS on it, I kissed goodbye to this very annoying problem.